# How to set animation on Bitmap in Canvas onDraw(), Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas, android-animation, bitmapfactory

Can anyone help me how to set animation on two bitmaps in Canvas?
I have two bitmaps `"bitmap1"` and `"bitmap2"`.

I want to display `"bitmap1"` and then `"bitmap2"` with interval of `500ms` then again `bitmap1` and so on this continues...
I want any method to do this but not using `Thread.sleep(500);`

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in the thread:

```
long lastBitmapSwitchMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();   //Saves system time from last bitmap switch
int currentBitmap = 1;   //1 = bitmap1, 2 = bitmap2
int bitmapInterval = 500;   //Interval between bitmap switches

while (running) {

     //Switches bitmap after interval
     if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= lastBitmapSwitchMillis + bitmapInterval) {
          lastBitmapSwitchMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();   //Save current time of bitmap switch
          if (currentBitmap == 1) {
               currentBitmap = 2;
          }
          else if (currentBitmap == 2) {
               currentBitmap = 1;
          }
     }

     //Render appropriate bitmap
     if (currentBitmap = 1) {
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, x, y, paint);   //x and y are bitmap's location,
     }
     else if (currentBitmap = 2) {
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, x, y, paint);   //x and y are bitmap's location
     }
}
```

Comment: go for <animation-list> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: Sadeshkumar's way is probably just as good if not better.  Thank you, Sadeshkumar.